# Integrating with Elavon

Tags: payment-processor

How does one setup the integration with Elavon Payment Processor?
Is there anything to do on the Elavon side?
Have you had good experience integrating CiviCRM with Elavon?

Answer (score 1):

The Elavon payment processor integration ships with CiviCRM https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/Elavon.php

From Administer > System Settings > Payment Processors, click Add Payment Processor. On New Payment Processor page, for Payment Processor Type, select Elavon Payment Processor and complete the rest of the form before submitting.

This is one of the oldest integrations with CiviCRM, and we have clients who have been happy with it for many years.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada, Elavon has monthly PCI fees of less than 10$/month requiring a yearly questionnaire be filled (else they add 20$ /month extra) and 5$/month admin fees but no setup fee, for a MID only account meaning no terminal.

Almost always, you can get a better rates when you have a trustworthy payment consultant offering different payment processors, like the one I have :-)

I'm about to put aside Stripe, I can let you know later how the switch went.